# The convergence of unordered sum

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$X$ is an arbitrary normed vector space. $A=\{x_i\in X\mid i\in J\}$ is an indexed set. $J$ contains the indices and is uncountably infinite. Let $\mathcal F=\{F\mid F\subseteq J, F \text{ is finite}\}$.

The following definition of the convergence of unordered sum is taken from https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m201b_old/sums.pdf. We claim that the unordered sum $\sum \limits_{i\in J}x_i$ converges if and only if $$\exists x\in X,\ \forall \varepsilon>0,\ \exists F_\varepsilon \in \mathcal F,\ \forall F_\varepsilon \subseteq F\in \mathcal F,\ \left\|\sum_{i\in F} x_i-x\right\|\leq \varepsilon.$$ Suppose the unordered sum $\sum \limits_{i\in J} x_i$ converges. Let $I\subseteq J$. Does $\sum \limits_{i\in I}x_i$ converge? (Note that it may converge to a different point) How to prove it? Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of convergence for the unordered sum? Convergence of the net of sums over finite subsets of $J$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes. Exactly. I will make a change and add the definition.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hi, BrianM, I added the definition. Can you help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I’m working on a couple other problems at the moment, but I will be giving this one some thought.

Comment: Why do you want $J$ to be uncountable?

Comment: @PseudoNeo If $J$ is finite, it is obvious. The uncountable case may be more interesting.

Comment: In this comment I will take your "claim" to be your _definition_.  Then there is the question of whether it is possible for your sum to converge in the sense you've defined if there are uncountably many indices $i$ for which $x_i\ne 0$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy It can be proved that if the unordered sum converges, the   nonzero elements are countable. The definition is not defined by myself. I take it from this lecture notes: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m201b_old/sums.pdf

Comment: @PseudoNeo I came up with this question when I was trying to prove the claim that every element in a Hilbert space can be written as the weighted sum of the orthonormal bases of the Hilbert space. But a Hilbert space can have a uncountable basis. So, that's how the uncountable sum comes from.

Comment: You should clarify in your question that when you say "converges" you mean possibly to a different element of the space.

Comment: @William I see. I will add it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ an *incomplete* normed space and $x_n\in X$ are such that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \|x_n\| <\infty$ but the series has no limit just take $I=\mathbb Z \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and $x_{-n}=-x_n$. The the series $\sum\limits_{n\in I} x_n$ converges with limit $0$ but the subseries $\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n$ does not converge. For *Banach* spaces the situation is opposite because you have the Cauchy criterion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How to prove that $\sum \limits_{n\in I} x_n$ converges to $0$ in this case? I guess it may converge in some order but not converge in another order.

Comment: As it converges absolutely any ordering converges to the same limit.  Given $\varepsilon >0$ and $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\sum_{n>N} \|x_n\| < \varepsilon/2$ is is enough to take $F_\varepsilon = I\cap \lbrace -N,\ldots,N\rbrace$.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple counter-example for this question. The answer is no.

Define a vector space $X=\mathbb{Q}$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$. $\mathbb{Q}$ is the collection of rational numbers. $X$ is equipped with the canonical distance $|\cdot|$. Now, we construct two nonnegative increasing sequences of rational numbers, $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. We let $a_n\rightarrow \sqrt{2}$, $b_n\rightarrow 2-\sqrt{2}$. Define $c_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$, $d_n=b_{n+1}-b_n$. So, $c_n\geq 0, d_n\geq 0$. So, $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty c_n=\sqrt{2}$, $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty d_n=2-\sqrt{2}$. Let $e_{2n-1}=c_n, e_{2n}=d_n$. We know $\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty e_n=2$.

From the above construction, we know if we let $A=\{e_n|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, $\sum \limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}e_n$ converges to $2$. But $2\mathbb{N}-1\subset \mathbb{N}$, $\sum \limits_{n\in 2\mathbb{N}-1}e_n=\sqrt{2}$, which doesn't converge in $X$. So, it is a contradiction.

Comment: Is $2N-1$ an abbreviation for the set of positive odd integers?

Comment: @Xianjin: Your definition of normed space allows $\mathbb Q$ to be the base field?

Comment: @BigbearZzz yes.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes. If I choose $R$ as the base field, $Q$ cannot form a vector space.

Comment: @XianjinYang It's often agreed that when one speak of a normed space, the base field is either $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb R$. That is probably his point.

Comment: @Xianjin: OK; if you were interested in finding examples with a complete base field, you could still work with an incomplete normed space, doing something similar.

Comment: @BigbearZzz I see. Maybe we can find another counter-example using the same strategy when the base is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks! I will try to figure out another example for $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.